# Do clustering on dataset but don't divide items with the same label

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset with 10k+ points. Some of the data is labeled into 100+ labels. The rest is to classify.

I cannot classify the new data directly as the number of labels is too high and the result doesn't look good enough.

So I want to learn clustering algorithm on the labeled dataset and divide roughly into 3-8 bins. I don't care which labels go into which group, but I want them to be concise. So the new data will be assigned into the correct cluster. And later on classified within model trained on a single bin.

Question: How to cluster dataset but force the algorithm to keep the different points in the same label in the same cluster?

Data:

| Id | Label | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | [...] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 3 | ... |
| 2 | A | 7 | 7 | ... |
| 3 | B | 10 | 9 | ... |
| 4 | B | 50 | 11 | ... |
| 5 | C | 91 | 15 | ... |
| 6 | C | 31 | 17 | ... |
| 7 | D | 0 | 19 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Expected outcome:

| Id | Label | **Cluster** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | **1** |
| 2 | A | **1** |
| 3 | B | **2** |
| 4 | B | **2** |
| 5 | C | **1** |
| 6 | C | **1** |
| 7 | D | **2** |
| ... | ... | ... |

I was trying to find a way to include the division in the loss function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KMeans from scikit-learn to achieve this, let us say your dataframe is df something like this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = df.drop(columns=['Label']).values

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)
df['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
print(df) # df should contain label and cluster for all the datapoints
```

Mixing of classes will happen no matter what clustering algorithm you use on the whole dataset. The other Idea is that you somehow embed all the datapoints of one class to a single vector by doing that you will have only 100+ vectors each representing one class after that cluster these 100+ vectors to any number of clusters you desire, then you will have no mixing.

Comment: That's what I have tried. But it ends up by mixing the classes.

Comment: See the suggestion above

Answer (score 0):

You could use mean-shift clustering or k-means clustering or DBSCAN on the labelled data to consolidate the labels into your 3 to 8 bins.  The parameters of these methods can be used to control the final number or binnings.

After clustering your labelled data.  You use the new binnings as your labels.  To apply the new labels to the non-labelled data, you could use k-nearest neighbors or DBSCAN again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I have added the label to the training data. But the k-means doesn't focus on the label and still mixes the classes. Any idea to put any focus or constrain on that one?